# Why other alternative method than using List.of

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
public List<Person> selectAllPeople() {
    return List.of(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "From Postgres DB"));
}
```

What other alternative I can use other than `List.of` to generate same output?

Comment: You could use [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.singletonList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-).

> Returns an immutable list containing only the specified object. The returned list is serializable.

```
return Collections.singletonList(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "From Postgres DB"));
```

Comment: You should be careful. There are subtle differences, e.g. https://ideone.com/Vbbgdo

Comment: @Michael so immutable != unmodifiable. Looks like you can just wrap the return value with a `unmodifiableList` call. e.g. `return Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.singletonList(new Person(UUID.randomUUID(), "From Postgres DB")));`

Comment: @Michael: why does that happen? Thanks.